# Perform Range Searches on Document Metadata using java api

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have xml and json documents stored in the database. My use case is that I need to fetch all the documents whose document creation date is lets say > (T-2), with T being the current date.
Hence, I added the document creation date and some other document properties in the document metadata. I can insert and retrieve all the properties that is required for the document. But can we perform the date range searches on the metadata properties??

I am using the StructuredQueryBuilder and it has the properties method where I am putting in the property name to fetch its value but don't have much idea about how to convert this into the range searches.

Comment: The first example in the Java Guide under "Structured Query Examples" is  "Date Range Structured Query"  does it meet your needs? http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/java/searches#id_66534

Comment: Also see "Example: Document Property Structured Query" http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/java/searches#id_74535 and the StructuredQueryBuilder.properties method.  Nevertheless, Justin's comment below is more helpful.  Best to keep out of properties.

Comment: Hi Sam.. Thanks for the reply but the first link provides the example for date range in the xml or data Content whereas the second link provides the example for searching a constant value in the properties. My use case is to do the range searches on the document properties. Does the range search on both the content and properties work the same say?? Example I have a range index on system date and I am issuing a query like.... 
{code}
Sqb.properties(Sqb. And(Sqb.range(constraint_name,type,operator,value)) )
{code}

Comment: Yes, you perform range search on both content and properties the same way.   You just need to set which fragment you're using: document or properties

Comment: Thanks Sam, I am able to do the range search for properties now

Answer (score 2):

It’s generally advisable to *avoid* document properties when you can. Querying across a document and its properties requires a join between two separate fragments, the unit of storage in MarkLogic. Joins are expensive, especially at scale. You should put your metadata in the document itself. If you need to segregate it from the main content you can create an envelope wrapper. For example, wrapping a document that represents a Customer entity,

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "createDate": …,
    "author": …, 
    "hash": …,
    …
  },
  "contents": {
    "customer": {
      …
    }
  }
}
```

The above is JSON, but you can use the same technique for XML as well.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could opt to use hidden metadata fields, which is a new feature in MarkLogic 9. You create a metadata field specifying only the name of the property, you then create a types field range index. You use them as any other field, but the value of these metadata fields do not show up as part of the document, even though they are internally tied to the document fragment for optimal performance. You use commands like `xdmp:document-set-metadata` to set the values, and there are also means to do this via the `/v1/documents` endpoint of the MarkLogic REST api.

HTH!